# how to use custom alert for switching the tab in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am creating a `react-router` prompt, so here I want to apply the alert message when you want to switch from one tab to another. I have applied the alert property for that I had create a function `confirmSwitchTab`, but it's not working. How do I make that prompt so that when I want to switch from one tab to another in every route, it shows the message.

```js
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import LoadingBar from "react-top-loading-bar";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Demo() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function confirmSwitchTab() {
    //Prompt the user with a confirm message.
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to switch tabs?");
    //If the user confirms, return true, else return false.
    if (result) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  const onClick = () => {
    const userConfirmsSwith = confirmSwitchTab()
    if (userConfirmsSwith) navigate("/")
    // else you don't do anything.
  }

  return (
    <>
      <LoadingBar
        color="blue"
        progress={progress}
        onLoaderFinished={() => setProgress(0)}
        waitingTime={800}
        loaderSpeed={100}
        height={4}
      />
      <ul
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-around",
          listStyle: "none"
        }}
      >
        <li>
          <Link
            to="/"
            onClick={() => {
              onClick();
              setTimeout(() => setProgress(100), 500)
            }}
          >
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link
            to="/about"
            onClick={() => {
              onClick();
              setTimeout(() => setProgress(100), 500)
            }}
          >
            About
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there has been a misunderstanding on how onLeave works here :-)

returning true is not going to "confirm the leave action". The leave action is confirmed no matter what. The onLeave prop will simple take a function and fire it when you leave the page. This function can be a prompt, like here, but the returned value won't be used.

What you are trying to achieve has to be done before the actual leave of the page. Somewhere in your app, you should have a navigation menu in which you actually make the page change on the button click (typically with

```
history.push("My/New/Path")
```

)

now that is where you want to use your function.

let's say you have something like

```
<Button onClick={history.push('home')} >Home</Button>
```

You want to call your confirmSwitchTab function in that callback.

you could change it into something like

```js
const onClick = () => {
  const userConfirmsSwith = confirmSwitchTab()
  if (userConfirmsSwith) history.push('home')
  // else you don't do anything.
}
<Button onClick={onClick}>Home</Button>
```

hope this helped, let me know if I got the problem wrong!

cheers

**After question edition**

try this:

```js
import { React, useState } from "react";
import LoadingBar from "react-top-loading-bar";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Demo() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  function confirmSwitchTab() {
    //Prompt the user with a confirm message.
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to switch tabs?");
    //If the user confirms, return true, else return false.
    if (result) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  const onClick = (path) => {
    setTimeout(() => setProgress(100), 500)
    const userConfirmsSwith = confirmSwitchTab()
    if (userConfirmsSwith) navigate(path)
    // else you don't do anything.
  }
  return (
    <>
      <LoadingBar
        color="blue"
        progress={progress}
        onLoaderFinished={() => setProgress(0)}
        waitingTime={800}
        loaderSpeed={100}
        height={4}
      />
      <ul
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-around",
          listStyle: "none"
        }}
      >
        <li>
          <Button onClick={() => {onClick("/")}>
            Home
          </Button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Button onClick={() => {onClick("/about")}>
            About
          </Button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: but in confirm message cancel button is not working ,when we click cancel how to say in same route, code is edited above , here ok button is working but not cancel button

Comment: That is because you use the "Link" component. The link component will send you to the provided URL no matter what, once again.

If you used a Button (like my example) and a history.push(), you would not have this problem.

Comment: I updated my answer as well, try it out

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because the code isn't preventing the default link action from occurring. The link is clicked and the navigation action is effected immediately, while at the same time the attached `onClick` handler is running other logic.

The click handler should consume also the click event object and call `preventDefault` on it to stop the navigation action from ocurring.

```
export default function Demo() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function confirmSwitchTab() {
    //Prompt the user with a confirm message.
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to switch tabs?");
  }

  const clickHandler = (target = "/") => (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- halt link navigation

    setTimeout(() => setProgress(100), 500);

    if (confirmSwitchTab()) {
      navigate(target);
    }
    // else you don't do anything.
  }

  return (
    <>
      <LoadingBar ... />
      <ul ... >
        <li>
          <Link to="/" onClick={clickHandler("/")}>
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about" onClick={clickHandler("/about")}>
            About
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```